# Difficulties to position my code with a grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to create a dashboard and I have some trouble to position all my elements using grid-layout.

This is the organisation that my dashboard is suppose to have :

```
img  img  nb  nb  members
Projects  nb  nb  
Collab    Activities
Asign
```

I initialize in my css code, a grid with 6 columns et 4 rows.

When I tried to set my elements using `grid-column` et `grid-row`, this is my result :

img  nb  projects  nb  collab  Asign
img  nb            nb
Members  Activities

Here is my HTML code :

```css
body
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.box
{
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
 border-color: #8000FF;
  padding: 20px;
}

.img {
 grid-column: span 2;
 grid-row: 1;
}

.projects {
 grid-column: span 1;
 grid-row: 1;
}

.nb {
 grid-column: span 2;
 grid-row: 1;
}

.members {
 grid-column: span 2;
 grid-row: 2;
}

.collab {
 grid-column: span 1;
 grid-row: 1;
}

.activities {
 grid-column: span 4;
 grid-row: 2;
}

.asign {
 grid-column: span 1;
 grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="img box">
   <article class="box">
    Photo 1
   </article>
   <article class="box">
    Photo 2
   </article>
  </div>

  <div class="nb box">
   <article class="box">
    35
   </article>
   <article class="box">
    19
   </article>
  </div>

  <aside class="members box">
   Membres
  </aside>

  <div class="projects box">
   Accédez à vos projets
  </div>

  <div class="nb box">
   <article class="box">
    170
   </article>
   <article class="box">
    1
   </article>
  </div>

  <div class="collab box">
   Invitez vos collaborateurs
  </div>

  <div class="activities box">
   Activités
  </div>

  <div class="asign box">
   Assignez vos projets
  </div>
```

Any ideas from where the problem is ?

Comment: that is a 3 or 6 columns, you seem to be confused about position and spanning . If you want to assign both, you need first to set the row or column's number, then add a slash, the keyword span and finally amount of cgrid cell to span . {grid-column:1/ span 2;` if there is no need to span, then `grid-column:1;` is enough. you can do this too for the row else , it will be set where there is room. example from your code and what i believe understood for the layout : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eqZobm. grid can also be imbricated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is NOT a **6** column grid - it seems to be a 3 column grid with each column split in two (based on your HTML).

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.box {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #8000FF;
  padding: 20px;
}

.img {
  grid-row: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.projects {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.nb-1 {
  grid-row: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.nb-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: flex;
}

.members {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.collab {
  grid-row: 3;
}

.activities {
  grid-row: 3;
  // grid-column: span 2;
}

.asign {
  grid-row: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="img box">
  <article class="box">
    Photo 1
  </article>
  <article class="box">
    Photo 2
  </article>
</div>

<div class="nb-1 box">
  <article class="box">
    35
  </article>
  <article class="box">
    19
  </article>
</div>

<aside class="members box">
  Membres
</aside>

<div class="projects box">
  Accédez à vos projets
</div>

<div class="nb-2 box">
  <article class="box">
    170
  </article>
  <article class="box">
    1
  </article>
</div>

<div class="collab box">
  Invitez vos collaborateurs
</div>

<div class="activities box">
  Activités
</div>

<div class="asign box">
  Assignez vos projets
</div>
</div>
```